# Ignoring projects from sonar goal execution

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have included sonar:sonar goal with Maven build for our multi module maven project. The build fails with error for projects that does not have a Java class:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3:sonar (sonar) on project PROJECT: Execution sonar of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3:sonar failed: Not a root project: org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectDefinition

Is there a way to exclude projects from sonar goal execution? Also is there a way to ignore sonar related errors in the build?

Comment: Also is there a way to ignore sonar related errors in the build?

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sonar execution is run on the parent project, all the child modules get reviewed, hence there is no need to put inherited this goal on child modules - setting inherited as false for the maven plugin solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to. Thanks.
My example (pom):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        **<inherited>false</inherited>**
        ...
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```